# Nested using blocks

Tags: c#, .net, using

I knew we could create more than one instance of the same type in a using block! but is there a way i could have different types instances nested or written in a single using block?

i just read this, so far it seems the only option 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericgu/archive/2004/08/05/209267.aspx

Comment: What's wrong with that option?

Comment: i was thinking.. wats wrong in writing using (type1 a = new Type1(), type2 b = new Type2) in most of my cases i would need to create two instances in using to do the th job. even thought to create a Helper Class which would actually do the job of both of them.

Comment: It's a lot more readable to use the two liner option

Comment: i wouldnt easily accept tat Oskar, because i am daily reading methods which has more than one parameter of different types :)

Comment: What does that have to do with this?

Comment: as you said (type1 a = new Type1(), type2 b = new Type2) is not good for readability.. i was just contradicting that by saying i daily see methods like Method( type1 a, type 2 b). so its not readability.. it should be some thing more than that which i dont know!

Comment: Well, that has nothing to do with this. That's a whole other thing. I did not say that the reason was readibility, I just said that it was more readable to use the two liner option. We are not talking about parameters here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not possible to have variables of different declared types in the same using statement.  The C# spec limits the set of valid constructs to a single expression or a local variable declaration.  The latter is covered in section 8.5.1 of the C# lang spec and only provides for a single variable type

```
local-variable-declaration:
  local-variable-type local-variable-declarators
```

To support different local variable types you need to use some form of nesting.  For example

```
using (Type1 local1 = new Type1(), local2 = new Type1())
using (Type2 local3 = new Type2(), local4 = new Type2())
{

}
```

Comment: Thanks Jared! Personally i dont like to leave the curly braces even if the IF had jus a single line.. i think i need to skip that thought to get this implemented.

Answer (score 1):

No. It is similar to the following:

```
int a, b;
```

Both a and b are int - that is it.